# Установка свойства schtasks через bat файл "Выполнять только для зарегистрированного пользователя"

Tags: cmd, bat

Бьюсь уже не первый день с проблемой.
Есть командная строка для cmd:

schtasks /CHANGE /TN "my_task" /RU user_login /RP pass /IT

которая меняет пароль для задачи в планировщике Windows, но проблема в том, что при выполнении команды сбрасывается пункт в задаче с "Выполнять только для зарегистрированного пользователя" на "Выполнять вне зависимости от регистрации". Что крайне мне не подходит, хотя использую параметр /IT

Answer (score 1):

О, тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой, но при создании задачи, нашел для себя такое решение:

```
echo.|schtasks.exe /Create /RU user_login /TN my_task
```

То есть без указания пароля /RP pass, но запуск батника с правами админа.

Если в командной строке запустить, без указания пароля, то запросит ввод пароля, я нажимаю сразу ввод (это эмулирует ввод "**echo.|**" без пробелов и с точкой) и  создается задача с "Выполнять только для зарегистрированного пользователя"